# How to choose the initial value of backpropagating Seed in neural network when using automatic differentiation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

This is not a question about initialization of weights or biases or anything, it is about implementing the automatic differentiation algorithm and choosing a correct initial seed/derivative to propagate with.

Suppose we have the following expression:
$$
Res = (X^{3x2} * Y^{2x4}) * A^{4x5}  \to Res^{3x5}
$$

When applying reverse-mode automatic differentiation, the first expression to get differentiated using the chain rule would be the outer dot product.

The rules, for Matrix Multiplication $C = A * B$, are($S$ stands for "Seed"):

1. The derivative w.r.t. the left "input" is: $\frac{\delta C}{\delta A} = S * B^T$
2. The derivative w.r.t. the right "input" is: $\frac{\delta C}{\delta B} = A^T * S$

From this follows, that Seed $S$ needs to be of same dimensionality as $Res$ ($3x5$).
Now, if the Seed $S$ could have been a scalar, a simple $1$ would have been enough, and if $Res$ were to be quadratic, then Seed $S$ would probably have been the Identity matrix $I$, but how to I initialise Seed $S$ in this case?

Can I even initialise it?

Comment: Why is the derivative $\delta C/\delta A$ equal to $S * B^T$? I don't follow. Could you tell me where these rules are from?

Comment: https://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/ and https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/mlpr/2017/notes/w5a_backprop.pdf

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\a{\c{{\cal E}}}\def\aa#1{\a_{#1}}
\def\d{\delta}\def\dd#1{\d_{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Use a colon to denote the Frobenius product,
which is a convenient notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
This is also known as the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the ordinary dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such a
product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= CB^T:A = A^TC:B \\
}$$
The fourth-order isotropic tensor can be defined in terms of Kronecker deltas as
$$\aa{j\ell km} = \dd{jk}\dd{\ell m}$$
and it can be used to rearrange matrix products
$$AXB = A\a B^T:X\\$$

---

Using the above tools we can address your question.

Start with the matrix product and calculate its differential and gradients
$$\eqalign{
C &= AB \\
dC &= A\,dB + dA\,B \\
 &= A\a:dB \;+\; \a B^T:dA \\
\grad{C}{B} &= A\a, \quad\quad\quad \a B^T = \grad{C}{A} \\
}$$
Comparing this to your "rules", we see that the Seed is actually a 4th order tensor $(\a)\,$ and the second gradient formula contains a spurious transpose.

**NB**: In matrix notation, juxtaposition implies a single-dot (aka single contraction) product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
ABC &= A\cdot B\cdot C \\
A\a C &= A\cdot \a\cdot C \\
}$$

Comment: Do you have references and possible citations for me? I would like to use this in a paper ...

Answer (score 1):

I think @Greg'answer is a bit complicated for your question. This may be because your nomenclature :  seed is not correctly defined and it does not exist in the given material.

The rules, for Matrix Multiplication $\mathbf{C=AB}$ are quite simple.
From
$$
d\mathbf{C}=(d\mathbf{A})\mathbf{B}+\mathbf{A}(d\mathbf{B})
$$
you easily deduce

$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{A}}=
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{C}}\mathbf{B}^T
$$

This relation indicates how yo obtain the sensitivity of the objective function wrt to a pertubation in $\mathbf{A}$ if the sensitvity wrt to $\mathbf{C}$ was known.

The initialization you indicate is the sensitvity to the last layer/variable and depends on the data at hand.

Comment: Yes, this is only really possible, beause the last layer is a scalar-valued cost function, which allows for the generation of an initial seed

Comment: I agree with you but to train a neural network you need that kind of scalar-valued cost function.

Comment: Sry for being unclear, thats what i meant. These derivatives can on ly be used this way *IN NEURAL NETS*, since they are terminated by scalar-valued cost functions. Sry for the confusion, i agree with you.