# Derivative of matrix w.r.t. itself

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

This sounds like a joke, but i am actually interested and would like an answer, but what is the derivative of a matrix $C$ w.r.t. itself?

$$
\text{What is: } \frac{\delta C}{\delta C}\text{?}
$$

Is it a matrix with shape equal to $C$ and filled with ones?

Comment: The scalar-valued function $$\phi=\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n C_{ij}$$ is the function whose gradient is the same shape as $C$ and filled with ones. But the gradient of $C$ wrt itself is a fourth-order **tensor**  as described in Siddarth's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A definition of the derivative of a matrix is provided in *[Kronecker Products & Matrix Calculus with Applications](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/kronecker-products-and-matrix-calculus-with-applications)* by A. Graham.

**Derivative of a matrix $\boldsymbol{Y}$ with respect to a scalar $x_{rs}$:**

In order to become familiar with the used notation we start with the derivative of a matrix with respect to a scalar. Let $\boldsymbol{Y}=\left(y_{ij}\right)$ be a matrix of order $(p\times q)$. The derivative of $\boldsymbol{Y}$ with respect to a scalar $x_{rs}$ is defined as the matrix
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{rs}}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_{11}}{\partial x_{rs}}&\frac{\partial y_{12}}{\partial x_{rs}}&\cdots
&\frac{\partial y_{1q}}{\partial x_{rs}}\\
\frac{\partial y_{21}}{\partial x_{rs}}&\frac{\partial y_{22}}{\partial x_{rs}}&\cdots
&\frac{\partial y_{2q}}{\partial x_{rs}}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\frac{\partial y_{p1}}{\partial x_{rs}}&\frac{\partial y_{p2}}{\partial x_{rs}}&\cdots
&\frac{\partial y_{pq}}{\partial x_{rs}}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=\sum_{i,j}E_{i,j}\frac{\partial y_{ij}}{\partial x_{rs}}
\end{align*}
with $E_{i,j}=\left(\delta_{k,i}\delta_{l,j}\right)_{{1\leq k\leq p}\atop{1\leq l\leq q}}$ the *elementary matrix* of order $(p\times q)$ which has a $1$ in the $(i,j)$-th position and all other elements are zero.

**Derivative of a matrix $\boldsymbol{Y}$ with respect to a matrix $\boldsymbol{X}$:**

We generalise the previous section in order to obtain the derivative of a matrix $\boldsymbol{Y}$ with respect to a matrix $\boldsymbol{X}$. Let $\boldsymbol{X}=\left(x_{rs}\right)$ be a matrix of order $m\times n$. The derivative of $\boldsymbol{Y}$ with respect to $\boldsymbol{X}$ is defined as the partitioned matrix
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{11}}&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{12}}&\cdots
&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{1n}}\\
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{21}}&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{22}}&\cdots
&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{2n}}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{m1}}&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{m2}}&\cdots
&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{mn}}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=\sum_{r,s}E_{r,s}\otimes\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{rs}}\tag{*}
\end{align*}
of order $(mp\times nq)$. Here we use the *[Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Definition)* $\otimes$. The definition (*) can be found in section 6.2.

> It follows from (*)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}
> =\sum_{r,s}E_{r,s}\otimes\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial x_{rs}}\tag{**}
> =\sum_{r,s}E_{r,s}\otimes E_{r,s}}
> \end{align*}

We note according to this definition $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}$ is not equal with the identity matrix $\boldsymbol{I}$.

**Example $\frac{\partial  \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}$ with $\boldsymbol{X}$ of order $(2\times 2)$:** We take a small matrix $\boldsymbol{X}$ of order $(2\times 2)$ and calculate $\frac{\partial  \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}$ to better see what's going on.

We obtain according to (*)
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial x_{11}}}&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial x_{12}}\\
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial x_{21}}&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial x_{22}}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{\frac{\partial x_{11}}{\partial x_{11}}}&\color{blue}{\frac{\partial x_{12}}{\partial x_{11}}}
&\frac{\partial x_{11}}{\partial x_{12}}&\frac{\partial x_{12}}{\partial x_{12}}\\
\color{blue}{\frac{\partial x_{21}}{\partial x_{11}}}&\color{blue}{\frac{\partial x_{22}}{\partial x_{11}}}
&\frac{\partial x_{21}}{\partial x_{12}}&\frac{\partial x_{22}}{\partial x_{12}}\\
\frac{\partial x_{11}}{\partial x_{21}}&\frac{\partial x_{12}}{\partial x_{21}}
&\frac{\partial x_{11}}{\partial x_{22}}&\frac{\partial x_{12}}{\partial x_{22}}\\
\frac{\partial x_{21}}{\partial x_{21}}&\frac{\partial x_{22}}{\partial x_{22}}
&\frac{\partial x_{21}}{\partial x_{22}}&\frac{\partial x_{22}}{\partial x_{22}}\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{0}&0&1\\
\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{0}&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{E_{11}}&E_{12}\\
E_{21}&E_{22}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{E_{11}}&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix}
0&E_{12}\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
E_{21}&0
\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
0&E_{22}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\color{blue}{E_{11}}\otimes E_{11}+E_{12}\otimes E_{12}+E_{21}\otimes E_{21}+E_{22}\otimes E_{22}
\end{align*}
in accordance with (**).

*Note:* Although we have $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}\ne\boldsymbol{I}$, when taking the transpose  $\boldsymbol{X^T}$ we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X^T}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}
=\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X^T}}{\partial x_{11}}}&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X^T}}{\partial x_{12}}\\
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X^T}}{\partial x_{21}}&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X^T}}{\partial x_{22}}
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{0}&0&0\\
\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{0}&1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{align*}
which is a *[permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix#Definition)* and so close to the identity matrix.

Comment: But it is the identity map. On the space of matrices and not the space of vectors. The derivative of a function $f: V \rightarrow W$ at $v\in V$ is a linear map $df(v): V \rightarrow W$. Here, $V$ and $W$ are the space of matrices of a given dimension (note that they need not be square). If $f$ is the identity map, then so is $df(v)$.

Comment: @Deane: It depends on the definition of the derivative of a matrix with respect to another matrix. According to this definition we have $\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}\ne \boldsymbol{I}$. See also the cited review which addresses this aspect.

Comment: Your formula is the identity. I do t understand how there could possibly be more than one definition

Comment: The formula for $E_{rs}$ in the review makes no sense to me. Perhaps you could explain?

Comment: To elaborate, the differential (or gradient) of a matrix-valued function of matrices, $f: M_{rs} \rightarrow M_{mn}$ should give the right answer for directional derivatives: $$ df(A)B = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}(A+tB). $$ If $f$ is the identity map, then $r=m$ and $s=n$. If $E_{rs}$ is the matrix with a $1$ in the $r$th row and $s$th column, then it is easy to check that $$ df(A)E_{rs} = E_{rs}, $$ which is exactly what you've written. It follows by linearity that $df(A): M_{rs} \rightarrow M_{rs}$ is the identity map.

Comment: @Deane: Many thanks for the elaboration, I see. I've added a small example which also might  be somewhat helpful.

Comment: I see what you're talking about. You're simply arranging the matrix differently. If you use yours correctly, then it will still be the identity map, even though your matrix doesn't look like the identity matrix.

Answer (score 3):

When differentiating an $n$ dimensional object by an $m$ dimensional object, we'll have $mn$ dimensions, showing how each of the $n$ dimensions varies with respect to each of the $m$ dimensions.

If we assume that the components of $(C)_{ij}$ are all independent, then when we differentiate, we are computing: $$\frac{d(C)_{ij}}{d(C)_{kl}}$$

which has four indexes $i, j, k, l$. Since we assume that $(C)_{ij}$ are all independent, we'll have:

$$
\frac{d(C)_{ij}}{d(C)_{kl}} \equiv
\begin{cases}
1 & i = k \land j = l \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

If $i = k$ and $j = l$, then the expression becomes $d(C)_{ij}/d(C)_{ij}$, which is $1$ since the derivative of any variable with respect to itself is $1$. If $i \neq k$ or $j \neq l$, then we get the derivative of some variable $(C)_{ij}$ by another independent variable $(C)_{kl}$, which is zero.

The above expression is sometimes compactly denoted as:

$$
\frac{d(C)_{ij}}{d(C)_{kl}} \equiv \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}
$$

where $\delta_{ik}$ is the [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

To wrap up, the derivative $d(C)_{ij}/d(C)_{kl}$ is a 4 dimensional object, indexed by $i, j, k, l$. It has an entry $1$ if $i = k$ and $j = l$, and zero otherwise.

Comment: This is frustratingly helpful, as it perfectly answers my question, but is not what i was hoping for ... maybe you know the answer. Do you know, what the initial value of a backpropagating algorithm is, if all operations are matrices?
EDIT: I was hoping for the ones matrix :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316004/how-to-choose-the-initial-value-of-backpropagating-seed-in-neural-network-when-u

Comment: Also note the anology to the derivative of a scalar function w.r.t. itself, namely, $\frac{dx}{dx} = 1\,.$

Comment: I am sorry for this late comment, but do you have a citation for this gradient, like a maths paper or something, such that i can cite this?